# How to Left align numbering of references

Tags: bibliographies

```
\renewcommand\refname{\zihao{4}参考文献}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\heiti 参考文献}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{thebibliography}{plain}  
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-2mm}
    \bibitem{ref1}1
                 \bibitem{ref2}2
                \bibitem{ref3}3
                \bibitem{ref4}4
\end{thebibliography}
\end{flushleft}
```

I've looked up a lot of information on the Internet, but what if I can't find it

I want to the "Left aligned numbering".

like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. Unfortunatly I cannot understand the difference between the "this is my" and "require".

Comment: Would you like to display reference as numbered with family name first? Which bib manager you are using, Biblatex or Bibtex?

Comment: @hesham You can see that the Numbers in my references are right-aligned.
But what I need is left alignment

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico I use “ctexart”

Comment: Please also tell us how you build the bibliography: by hand, or with a software tool such as bibtex or biblatex? Which bibliography style, if any, do you employ?

Comment: @Mico I think the option of building the bibliography "by hand" may be a result of being unaware of other automated methods.

Comment: @Mico I use by hand

Comment: @我心永恒  You could be wasting a lot of time here if you are building them "by hand". You may only do so if you are after a very unique or unusual style, which I don't see in your English reference entries.

Comment: @hesham I need to change the font of the reference and so on. If I use bibtex, it will be difficult to operate.
So I chose to add the directory by hand, which I had to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it may not be the best practice, but if you want to left align the "numbers" themselves of the reference numbering, and add bib entries *by hand*, then you can use `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` (which could be good until 99 references, before overlapping with numbers), then you can get something like this:

[image]

The complete code of which is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{ref1} Ref. 1
    \bibitem{ref2} Ref. 2
    \bibitem{ref3} Ref. 3
    \bibitem{ref4} Ref. 4
    \bibitem{ref5} Ref. 5
    \bibitem{ref6} Ref. 6
    \bibitem{ref7} Ref. 7
    \bibitem{ref8} Ref. 8
    \bibitem{ref9} Ref. 9
    \bibitem{ref10} Ref. 10
    \bibitem{ref11} Ref. 11
\end{thebibliography}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that by using this method, you will keep the "numbers" left aligned but you will lose the alignment of the reference entries themselves. I noticed the entries alignment are lost anyway in your posted question picture. 祝好運!

Comment: I feel good ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This answer did not fulfill the intention of the OP question due to initial lack of understanding. However, I thought it could be useful for some other beginners.

---

**Original Answer**

The display of the numbered references is usually left aligned by default. First you have to decide you need `Bibtex` solution or `Biblatex` for managing your reference. If you are submitting an article to a journal, they usually require Bibtex, otherwise (e.g. writing your own report or book), using Biblatex is by far much better since it allow much more control, many styles, and easier handling for managing how you display your citations and references.

Since you did not specify which, I will assume you are seeking the `Bibtex` solution. For using numbered references with the author first name abbreviated and then family name, you may use `ieeetr` bibliography style. There are other variants with other order and numbering styles, e.g. `acm` (numbered but capitalized author family name comes first), `plain`, ..etc (and of course a lot more customization available with `biblatex`). The `natbib` and its options controls how the display of inline citation of reference within the document main body will look (numbered, author-year style, etc).

So here is an example you may need to structure your document like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % for using at inline citations which appears as numbers
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} % the style that display and order references
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % OPTIONAL
%
\title{Your paper title}
\author{Yoshikazu Kawaguchi}
%
\begin{document}
%
\maketitle
%
\section{Introduction}
In order to cite one reference, you can use cite command like this \cite{Doe_2020}. You can also cite two references like this \cite{Doe_2020,Tenis_2000}.
%
\bibliography{reference} % list of references is printed here
%
\end{document}
```

For this example, you will need to place your references in a separate file `reference.bib` like this

```
@Book{Doe_2020,
  author    = {John Doe},
  publisher = {John Wiley},
  title     = {Differential equations : an introduction to modern methods and applications},
  year      = {2020},
  address   = {New Jersey},
  isbn      = {9780471651413},
  keywords  = {Differential equations},
  language  = {In English},
}

@Article{Tenis_2000,
  author  = {Michael Tenis},
  journal = {Jounal of Energy},
  title   = {New article about something},
  year    = {2000},
  month   = aug,
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {66--88},
  volume  = {2},
}
```

This will finally produce the following output:

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion is very good, I need to change the font of the reference or something, if I use bibtex, it will be difficult to operate.
So I chose to add the directory manually, which I had to do.
My main problem is that the reference number is not left-aligned.
What I need is for the reference Numbers to be left aligned.
Ps: I used Google translation, forgive my poor English

Comment: My suggestion was NOT good at all, because I thought you mean left aligning the numbered references, not the "numbers" themselves. Now I think of deleting this answer.