# Aligning Biblatex items left

Tags: biblatex

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547024/how-to-left-align-numbering-of-references) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/bibtex-key-alignment-and-localization) I am searching for a way to align the numbers on the left. I am using `biblatex`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label format is controlled by the bibliography environment. To change the label alignment, change `\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}` to `\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1}`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum,
worman,knuth:ct:a,aksin,gaonkar:in,
moraux,pines,westfahl:space,jaffe}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Left-aligned numbers.]